# How to save rows to files in UTF-8?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to split large txt files into multiple txt files (encoding UTF-8). The language I'm working with is Asian.

I tried some VBA and Python code but I can't make this work.

```
Sub ExportTextFiles()

Dim i As Long
Dim LastDataRow As Long
Dim MyFile As String
Dim fnum


    LastDataRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LastDataRow
        'The next line uses the contents of column A on the same row to name it
        MyFile = "C:\Users\grego\Downloads\" & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value & ".txt"
        'Use the following line instead to just create a series of numbered files
        'MyFileName = "C:\Users\grego\Downloads\" & i & ".txt"
        fnum = FreeFile()
        Open MyFile For Output As fnum
        Print #fnum, Format(Range("B" & i))
        Close fnum
    Next i

End Sub
```

This macro works well but the output is ANSI and instead of Unicode I get strings of question marks. Any help would be much appreciated! I could use some python too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ADO-Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/stream-object-ado?view=sql-server-2017) objects to read and write utf-8 files.

```
Public Function ReadUTF8(f As String) As String
    Dim st As Object
    Set st = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    st.Charset = "utf-8"
    st.Open
    st.LoadFromFile f
    ReadUTF8 = st.ReadText
    st.Close
    Set st = Nothing
End Function

Public Sub WriteUTF8(f As String, content As String)
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    Dim st As Object
    Set st = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    st.Charset = "utf-8"
    st.Open
    st.WriteText content
    st.SaveToFile f, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    st.Close
    Set st = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then you only need this inside the loop:

```
MyFile = "C:\Users\grego\Downloads\" & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value & ".txt"
WriteUTF8 MyFile, ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Text
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I use this with my macro above?

Comment: You just build the filename and call these two methods inside your loop for reading and writing. I thought this part is trivial. Where exactly do you have problems?

Comment: It doesn't work if I put them inside the loop of my macro. Would you mind showing me where to insert them. I'd be so grateful!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So how should the whole thing look like if we put all this together? I tried to do it but it failed.

Comment: I got it right! Many warm thanks for your kind help